# Silverlight MVVM binding and use of extended class property

Tags: silverlight, mvvm

I've got a class with a city and country property, which I extend to combine the two values.

```
public class Area
{
public string City;
public string Country;
}
```

This is exposed to Silverligt by a RIA Service and I have a extension

```
public partial class Area
{
public string AreaString
{
get { return City + ", " + Country;}
}
```

In my XAML a datagrid is using the AreaString

```
<sdk:DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AreaCollection}"
                      Name="dataGrid1" Width="Auto">
    <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
        <sdk:DataGridTextColumn CanUserReorder="True" IsReadOnly="True"  Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding Path=AreaString}" />                
            </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
        </sdk:DataGrid>
```

This datagrid is bound to a dataform where I may edit the Country and City properties with a two way binding. But how am I supposed to get the datagrid "updated" with the new values? To trigger a new get of the AreaString property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `OnPropertyChanged` like below after you implement INotfiyPropertyChanged interface:

```
public partial class Area
{
    public string AreaString
    {
        get 
        { 
            return City + ", " + Country;
            OnPropertyChanged("AreaString");
        }
    }
}
```

You should also add `OnPropertyChanged("AreaString");`  in the City **AND** Country setters.

**Update**

An alternative to this is to extend either the `OnCityChanged` or the `OnCityChanging` partial methods that exist with your entity.  Like:

```
partial void OnCityChanged()
{
    OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("AreaString"));
}
```

Comment: What good does calling PropertyChanged do in the getter?  Will that code even execute since it is after the return?  If it does execute, won't it cause an infinite loop because every time you retrieve the value, it will tell silverlight that the value has change and should be read again.

Comment: But then I would need to change the orignal class, which I really don't want to do. Perhaps a better solution is to use a templatecolumn in the datagrid

Comment: @Kman - see update. If you are exposing entities?  If not, then the first way should still work for you.

Answer (score 2):

When you touch City or Country you should notify the PropertyChanged event for AreaString too.
In order to achieve this, you should also make Area implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx)
A sample on how to use it is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614.aspx).

Comment: The AreaCollection which the grid is bound to is a ObservableCollection<Area> from my ViewModel. I don't quite see how I am supposed to handle/catch the propertychanged in my viewmodel, even when implementing INotifyPropertyChanged on the Area class

Comment: @Kman in order to observe the single elemnt inside the colelction, even the element has to be "observable" thus you need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: I've added the interface to my partial class definition, but I'm afraid I don't see where to go next

Comment: @Kman the problem is on using the INotifyPropertyChange implementation ? I add an example link in the reply